# Developing business logic part of Android projects with relying on building the UI

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, software-design

I had a console chatting application in kotlin, then I refactored the code to two subprojects, with one for networking and the other for CLI functionality.

I later developed the UI for a native Android App, and now that I wanted to merge the former core networking module, I'm unsure how my development flow will go, meaning that 'How am I supposed to inspect requests output? How further enhancements and features are to be developed?' Should I bind them directly to the UI at the App, or continue printing out results to the stdout (without the UI building overhead)?

 My current inclination is building the core logic independent of the UI, and once it's fully mature I can start integrating it with the UI part

I'm not even sure if developing the core logic using manual logging to stdout is even a good approach for general software development, not to mention Android development.